# Cannot access variable inside jQuery.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a function that is in one of my objects:

```
updatePorts: function(nodeKey, portOptions, portArrays) {
  var showing_ports = false;
  $('#ports li').removeClass('active').hide();
  $('#ports .tab-pane').removeClass('active in');
  $.each(portOptions, function(side, options) {
    if (options.editable) {
      $('#ports [href="#'+side+'"]').closest('li').show();
      if (!showing_ports) {
        $('#ports [href="#'+side+'"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
        $('#ports #'+side).addClass('active in');
      }

      $.each(portArrays[side], function(i,port) {
        //do stuff
      }

      showing_ports = true;
    }
  })
}
```

My problem is that outside of the `$.each` loop I **can** access the `portArrays` variable that is passed as an argument into the function. However, I **cannot** access that same variable inside of the `$.each` loop.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I gain access to that variable inside the loop?

**UPDATE: Added code where portArrays is actually being accessed**

Comment: Your code doesn't show the error case.  You are not accessing portOptions inside the each loop, so how can we say what is wrong with your code?

Comment: there is no reason portArrays wouldn't be accessible inside the each loop

Comment: I've added some code accessing portArrays. I will see if I can recreate my issue in jsfiddle

Comment: You have to fire up your debugger and take a look at what value ``portArrays`` has inside the first ``each`` block.

Comment: I did. It is undefined when it is inside the first each block. Before the first each block it is an object.

Answer (score 0):

`portArrays` *is* defined where you're using it, but you're using the wrong index. The `side` variable is an index into `portOptions`, not `portArrays`.

What index should it have? If these two arrays run in parallel with the same index values, that's generally a bad idea - it's better to use a single array of objects - and at least needs to be documented in your code.

BTW, what is the exact error message in the JS console? If my guess isn't right, the error message would give a clue.

Comment: After rewriting the code in jsfiddle everything seems to be working fine. Not sure what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem described in the subject, however it seems the asker had a problem elsewhere in his code. My code is similar to the below and I could not access what I wanted from `this`. The first log would work, but the log inside the each loop was undefined. I realise now that `this` is reassigned when using jquery each - http://api.jquery.com/each/

```
List.prototype.updateList = function(search) {
    console.log(this.id);
    $.each(this.data, function(item, tags) {
        console.log(this.id); //undefined
    };
}
```

I've changed to using `for .. in` to iterate my this.data object and it's working. Hope this may help someone.

```
List.prototype.updateList = function(search) {
    console.log(this.id);
    for(var key in this.data){
        console.log(this.id); //hooray
    }
}
```